# Global instances of class

Tags: c#, wpf, class, singleton, instance

Still trying to get to know C# (Mostly worked with C). I have a class "Device" and would like to create an instance of the class, but would also like access to the instances globally because I use them so much in my GUI methods.

```
 public class Device
    {
        public string Name;
        public List<string> models = new List<string>();
        public List<string> revisions = new List<string>();
        ...
    }
```

Somehow declare this globally:

```
 Device Device1 = new Device();
 Device1.Name = "Device1";
```

Then access it later in a WPF method:

```
 private void DeviceViewItem_Selected(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
       TreeViewItem selected = (TreeViewItem)sender;

        if (selected.Name == Device1.Name)
        {
            Device1.Models.Add("something");
            Device1.Revisions.Add("something");
        }
```

I've been reading about singleton Pattern, but it looks like you have to create a Singleton Class, but my "Device" Class is used multiple times to create many devices. Maybe I just don't understand the pattern that well.

Comment: You're looking for `static`.

Comment: If you need multiple Singletons, you could look into the [Multiton pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiton_pattern).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Create a new instance and assign it to a [**static**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/98f28cdx.aspx) property or field:

```
public class AnyClass
{
    public static readonly Device ThisFieldCanBeReachedFromAnywhere = new Device();
}
```

Note that the class AnyClass doesn't have to be static (that would however mean that all members **must** be static).

Also note that the readonly keyword isn't required, it is just good practice for singletons (like Mark suggested in his comment).

Comment: possibly making it readonly as well.  This is common for the singleton.

Comment: LightBricko, exactly what I needed. I was looking everywhere and came across Static members, but didn't think of creating a New Instance Statically. Thanks!

Comment: @Mark Thanks for mentioning readonly. Definitely want to stick with good practices;)